# Luggage use of someone absent

Tags: luggage, europe, ryanair

I bought two tickets for my parents on the same flight, but my father is not coming anymore. Can my mother use the luggage allowance of my dad on the way back? Since the ticket is still bought and not used.

Comment: I believe you need to check with the airplane company. However, it looks like that it is not allowed. Specially, the suitcases must have the owner name, and in this case, your father will not in the airplane.

Comment: There's a possibility that the airline overbooked the plane, hoping that some passengers won't show, in this case this includes your dad. But the airline also expects non-showing passengers not to have any luggage, so they can use the space for those that do show.

Comment: If your father does not board the aircraft on the outbound leg of the trip, the return ticket will almost certainly be cancelled.  So even if once could use the "unused" baggage allowance of someone who had a ticket but wasn't on the flight, that wouldn't apply here:  your father's return ticket will no longer be valid.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is NO for several reasons.

Baggage allotment is per ticketed passenger. Your father's allotment will not be available if he does not check in, because he would be a "no show" not a "passenger" on that flight.  For the same reason his seat would not be available either for your mother to have more room.

Secondly, since you are looking at the return flight to use the allotment, when your father is a no show for the first flight the return booking would be cancelled, so there would be no allotment to even be considered.

Comment: Or more accurate, luggage allotment is per contract, and 2 passengers have a contract each. A single person could buy 2 tickets and check in on both of them, thus using the luggage allotments for both, but that won't work if the tickets are in different names.

Comment: @jwenting - Not going to get into a long debate over terminology, but "contract" and "passenger" are essentially the same here, but "passenger" is more understandable to the novice traveler.  A single person buying two seats for themselves would be two "passengers" or two "contracts" to the airline reservation system and two check in's for the agent or OCI.

Comment: Though usually and AFAIK, if a person wants to buy 2 seats for space reasons, 1. the second seat has to be booked with a special name and 2. the second seat doesn't have any luggage applicable.

Answer (score 4):

In some cases it is necessary to book an extra seat, e.g. for very big stuff that needs to go as hand luggage, e.g. music instruments like a classical bass.
You could try and ask the airline, if the seat you originally booked for your father can be changed to/used as an extra seat by your mother.

Rebooking the seat to become an extra seat might add a fee. Also your airline might have a strict policy on luggage, e.g. because they doubt your mother can handle the number of luggage pieces.

In any case, "ask the airline" is certainly the correct answer. In the worst case, they say "no".